# Query Database, Rearrange, Insert into new table

Tags: java, mysql

I already have a database with every user's scores and other stats. But the scores aren't organized in any way that make it usable to make a leaderboard rank.

If the table looks something like this:

```
+----------+-------+-----+ 
| Username | Score | ... |
+----------+-------+-----+
|   UserA  | 900   | ... |
+----------+-------+-----+
|   UserB  | 200   | ... |
+----------+-------+-----+
|   UserC  | 850   | ... |
+----------+-------+-----+
|   UserD  | 450   | ... |
+----------+-------+-----+
```

There is no relation to position in the database and score. Now, what I want to do is create a query of the database collecting the scores for each user, then rearranging them by score. I figure this would be something like ORDER BY score DESC.

After ordering them in the correct way, I want to input the new values into a table with only username and rank, which I can query ingame to tell the rank of any given player requested.

ex:

```
+----------+------+ 
| Username | Rank |
+----------+------+
|   UserA  | 1    |
+----------+------+
|   UserC  | 2    |
+----------+------+
|   UserD  | 3    |
+----------+------+
|   UserB  | 4    |
+----------+------+
```

Now if I quered rank where username=UserA I would get 1

So what is my question? How do I, in java, query the database for score & username then rearrange the values into a new table based on the numerical rank, not score.

Comment: There are so many different methods of manipulating databases with Java. You could find inifinity tutorials using a google search of `java mysql query` If you come back with specific questions, then this is the correct place to get help. Your logic is sound, but the code will not be written for you. As a side not, you know that this could be done strictly with SQL statements right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specific user, this might work:

```
select username, score, (select count(h.username)+1 from users u, (select username, score from users) h where u.username = 'UserG' and (h.score > u.score)) as 'rating' from users where username = 'UserG';
```

Problem with setting a variable @rank like Alain suggested would be in case of duplicate scores, what if 2 users have a score of 100? Query above will rate them both as #5, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282322/sql-numbering-the-rows-returned-by-a-select-statement).

In general it's better to just select ordering by score and then put the query result into an array list. 0th item would be the person with the best score, 1st item person with second score, etc.

If you really need to select with ranking in the result set try using one of the examples in the linked discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The "In Java" is the only confusing part of your question.  You want something like:

```
CREATE TABLE leaderboard (username varchar(50), score int unsigned, rank int unsigned)

INSERT INTO leaderboard (username, score, rank) SELECT username, score, @rank:=@rank+1 FROM scores_table, (SELECT @rank:=0) as run_once order by rank desc;
```

Untested, but that would be the concept.  When it comes time to recalculate the leaderboard just:

```
DELETE * from leaderboard;

INSERT INTO leaderboard (username, score, rank) SELECT username, score, @rank:=@rank+1 FROM scores_table, (SELECT @rank:=0) as run_once order by score desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the database, um, return the data you need in the format you want:

```
set @rank = 0;
select username, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from user_scores
order by score desc
```

No Java magic required.

Comment: But if I want to query for a specific user, do I do

`set @rank = 0;

select username, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank

from user_scores

where username="userA"

order by score desc
`

Comment: What happened when you tested it?  It didn't work, right?  (Because the WHERE clause removed all of the other users from the ranking!).  Try `HAVING username = "userA"` instead.